# Include PDF hbox is too wide, annoying blank page

Tags: graphics, positioning

I include a pdf in my latex document but latex says it is too wide.
In default configuration for any reason latex includes the pdf in the horizontal center of the page. That's why i'm using

```
\vspace*{-1cm}\hspace*{-2cm}\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{}
```

This command will move the pdf to the left and I can print the document without a format problem. BUT, latex insterts a blank page above my pdf because the command just changed the pdf position and it is still too wide.
It is no option to change the scaling of the pdf because the size is perfect as it is. Just latex does not recognize I've changed the margin to the right side.

```
(Overfull \hbox (25.35355pt too wide))
```

Someone an idea how I can remove that blank page? One possible solution could be to include the pdf not in the horizontal center of my page, but I don't know either how to do that.

Comment: the blank page is not caused by the width, it is presumably also too high. Best would be to fix the size of the included image but putting `\hspace{-26pt}` immediately after `\includegraphics ` will make the warning go. You probably need somethikng similar in vertical direction as well

Comment: I tested your answer, but it is not the height. I have many space between the end of the page an my pdf. I have just the warning that hbox is too wide. it seems vbox is ok.

and using \hspace{-26pt} will move my pdf to the left side of the page. This would look awful. -2cm will center the pdf but latex think it's going out of the page.

Comment: AFTER the \includegraphics, not before.  You could also use \rlap{\includegrahics{...}}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.